# NETWORK ERR in Laravel when API requested from Vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, cors

I was updating my laravel app when I noticed that in the server, one of the requests was throwing a `NETWORK ERR`, I researched about it and found out that this may be due to cors policy. I was using a self created cors middleware, after this issue, I download the `fruitcake/laravel-cors' package but this did not solve the problem.
The thing is that this is working fine in my localhost before and still. The problem only occurs in server. If I could replicate this error in my local, maybe I could find the problem and solve it.
Here is my cors.php file:

```
<?php

    return [
    
        'paths' => ['api/authenticate'],
    
        'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
    
        'allowed_origins' => ['*'],
    
        'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
    
        'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
    
        'exposed_headers' => [],

        'max_age' => 0,

        'supports_credentials' => true,
    ];
```

And I have registered it like:

```
    protected $middleware = [
\Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    ];
```

I specifically added `api/authenticate` to the path because that was the specific path throwing the error. Also the response is completely empty. Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE:

To clarify my problem, there are 2 api endpoints in my server say https://www.a.com/api/login and https://www.a.com/api/authenticate. Both are post requests and the response header to the first one (working) is:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.a.com
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 140
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Fri, 02 Jul 2021 13:21:05 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
Vary: Origin,Accept-Encoding
X-RateLimit-Limit: 60
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 59
```

and the response to the 2nd one (the problem) is:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Connection: close
Content-Length: 3255
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Fri, 02 Jul 2021 13:21:49 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
```

and the console prints this as error exception:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.b.com/api/authenticate' from origin 'https://www.a.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

I am a bit confused but this looks as if the preflight request is being rejected by the server incase of the second request.

Comment: Did you check the logs for errors? Because any non 200 response to a OPTION request will cause an CORS error

Comment: Yeah, this is not an OPTION request, also I read this might be a cors error but I'm not sure myselff.

Comment: OPTION requests are send by the browser as part of CORS

Comment: No I did't see anything in logs. No mention of this issue.

Comment: Also the response is 200, tested in local